# iPhone Subview Transparent

Tags: iphone, transparent, subview

I subclassed a subview and added it to the current view. It draws a simple circle by overriding the draw method.

But the subview has a black background it looks like by default. How do I make the background of my subclassed subview to be transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can call next code into view initialization:

`self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`